# Searborn square grid

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have the code below, it works perfectly. So, I`ve looking for a way to plot the grid in a square shape.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0,10]
y = [7, 0]
z = [5,0]

sns.lineplot(x = x, y = y)
sns.lineplot(x = x, y = z)

plt.xlabel("Hand Activity Level")
plt.ylabel("Normalized peak force")
plt.title("TLV for Hand Activity")

plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0))
plt.yticks(np.arange(min(y), max(y)+2, 1.0))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

For example, in this code, the grid intersection 0 and 0 is a rectangle, 0 and 1, and so on. I would like to display all grids as squares. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean using `plt.margins(0)`?

Comment: Ohh, yeah, I forget to use that. It worked pretty well. Many thanks.